# I am trying to get the received time of a mail by using Python but getting the below error everytime

Tags: python, python-3.x, outlook, message

```
import win32com.client,sys
from datetime import datetime
now=datetime.now()
outlook=win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox=outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages=inbox.Items
message=messages.Getlast
received_time=str(message.ReceivedTime)
print(received_time)
received_time=datetime.strptime(received_time,"%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S")
print(received_time)
```

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/...Outlook_Automation.py", line 29, in 
>       received_time=message.ReceivedTime.datetime.strftime("%d-%m-%y %H:%M %p")
>     File "C:\Users....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 516, in **getattr**
>       ret = self.*oleobj*.Invoke(retEntry.dispid,0,invoke_type,1)
>   ValueError: hour must be in 0..23

Comment: As the error states `ValueError: hour must be in 0..23` looks like message.ReceivedTime is not valid

Comment: what is output of `print(received_time)`?

Comment: No output, Error is showing on the line before that only